# Criterion of Identity for 'set'

Tags: set-theory, foundations, philosophy

I'm looking for different criteria of identity for the notion of 'set'. I know that the standard criterion of identity is extensionality but I was wondering if there are others. I looked around but couldn't find any literature on other criteria. I thought you could help me find some material on that topic?

Thanks for taking the time. All the best,

David

Comment: The MathOverflow [post about set theory without extensionality](https://mathoverflow.net/q/168287/28209) is related, but not quite the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Extensionality is an axiom in ZF set theory; the '=' relation is built-in, i.e., part of the basic apparatus of predicate logic.

(Usually. If you treat '=' as a defined symbol via Extensionality, then you need to explicitly postuate the substitution properties of it.)

However, you said "criterion", so I guess that amounts to the same thing.

You could reverse the direction of the $\in$ relation:
$$ x=y \Leftrightarrow \forall z(x\in z \Leftrightarrow y\in z)$$
In ZF, this is a theorem: the Pair axiom gives us the singletons $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$, and one can show that $y\in \{x\}\Leftrightarrow y=x$. From this it's a short step to this "reversed extensionality".

The founders of axiomatic set regarded extensionality as basic to the very concept of a set. It comes from the notion of "extension of a property", and is the key feature that distinguishes "property" from "set" (or collection or class).

If you seach for "extensionality" in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/), you will find a number of articles that may bear on your question, depending on how it's interpreted.